# Lenovo WMI BIOS Changes save on second run only

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have made a powershell script to look for things matching certain bios settings and then change them.

the only issue is, if i run it once and reboot it doesn't save the settings although i have success returns. If i run it twice, the settings are saved.

I think it has something to do with my variables and the foreach statements. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
#param ([string]$lenovopass)
$lenovopass= "password"

#Search BIOS for Virtual or Items starting with V.
$biosvalues= gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | 
            Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -match “Virtual” -or $_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -like "V*”} |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty CurrentSetting
$biossplit= $biosvalues.split(",")[0,1]

#savebiossettings
$SaveBiosPass =(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings("$lenovopass,ascii,us") | Out-Null
$SaveBios =(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings() | Out-Null
$passcheck= (Get-WmiObject -namespace root\wmi -class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings | select -ExpandProperty PasswordState)

Function Lenovonopass{
foreach ($value in $biosvalues)
        {If ($value -match "Enable")
            {
            Write-Host "Found $value"
            Write-Host "Current Setting: $value"
            Write-Host "No changes made, $value already enabled."       
            } else { 
            Write-Host "Found $value"
            Write-Host "Current Settings: $value"
            $value = $value.split(",")[0,1]
            $valuea= $value[0]
            $valueb= $value[1]
            Write-Host "Changing $value state to Enable"
            (gwmi -class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -namespace root\wmi).SetBiosSetting(“$valuea,Enable”) | Out-Null
            $SaveBios
            $newvalue = gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | 
                        Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -match "$valuea"} | 
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty CurrentSetting
            write-host "New Settings: $newvalue"                
                    }
                }
        }       
Function LenovoPass{
foreach ($value in $biosvalues)
        {If ($value -match "Enable")
            {
            Write-Host "Found $value"
            Write-Host "Current Setting: $value"
            Write-Host "No changes made, $value already enabled."       
            } else { 
            Write-Host "Found $value"
            Write-Host "Current Settings: $value"
            $value = $value.split(",")[0,1]
            $valuea= $value[0]
            $valueb= $value[1]
            Write-Host "Changing $value state to Enable"
            (gwmi -class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -namespace root\wmi).SetBiosSetting(“$valuea,Enable,$lenovopass,ascii,us") | Out-Null
                $SaveBiosPass
                $newvalue = gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | 
                        Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -match "$valuea"} | 
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty CurrentSetting
            write-host "New Settings: $newvalue"
            Write-Host ""               
                    }
                }
        }       

IF ($passcheck -eq "0")
{Lenovonopass
$SaveBios
Write-Host "BIOS Changes Saved"
} Else {
Lenovopass
$SaveBiosPass
Write-Host "BIOS Changes Saved"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to save the bios settings by calling a variable like it would be a function.

```
$SaveBios
Write-Host "BIOS Changes Saved"
```

The only time you save the settings is in the beginning of the script when you assign a value to `$SaveBios`.
So by running the script twice, you are saving the settings in the beginning of the script which you changed in the run before that.

You could instead create a function for SaveBios. Or assign the value to `$SaveBios`when you actually want to save the settings.

```
IF ($passcheck -eq "0")
{Lenovonopass
$SaveBios =(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings() | Out-Null
Write-Host "BIOS Changes Saved"
} Else {
Lenovopass
$SaveBiosPass =(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings("$lenovopass,ascii,us") | Out-Null
Write-Host "BIOS Changes Saved"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer David, curious though. If i declare the variable $savebios in the begging with the commands it is supposed to execute, why wouldnt i be able to call that variable at the end to perform those commands?

Comment: After adding the that as a function and calling the functions it has saved on the first time now. Thanks again.

Comment: @user160396
I'm not sure if I understand. By calling `$savebios` you are basicly displaying or using the value.
You are assigning a value to the variable, not executing a command.

When you declare the variable in the beginning, the "command" need to be executed in order for you to assign the value to the variable.